# How to use SUM over GROUP BY in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM DataTable
WHERE Name IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY Name
```

Resulting output:

```
Name    Total
--------------
 A        2
 B        5
 C        3
```

Instead I want this:

```
Name    Total
--------------
 A        10
 B        10
 C        10
```

Here 10 is a total of 2 + 5 + 3 (total number of records with name = A/B/C)

How do I do this?

Comment: What's the point of displaying this figure for `a`, `b` and `c` individually then? Can you explain the logic behind the requirement?

Comment: Well, actually in a real query I using the offset and limit to fetch only initial 10 records, on the next run I will be fetching next 10.
I need the total count to display the total number of records for pagination purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get your desired result you can use `SUM() OVER ()` on the grouped `COUNT(*)`. [Demo](http://rextester.com/UTAA40274)

```
SELECT Name, 
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as Total
FROM DataTable
WHERE Name IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Any idea on how this would compare vs. `distinct .... count(*) over()` on a larger data set? Plans look similar (shifted sort operator placement) on the really simple example data. [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=605b51a0e0edd266c9ed2e5ec037691e)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was wondering the same regarding the performance.

Comment: @SqlZim I'm on IPad so can't test and look at the plans. I imagine this would be preferable though as it can reduce the row count earlier. I am imagining the plan for yours may well spool as many rows as in the whole table?

Comment: @MartinSmith the plans don't show up on [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=605b51a0e0edd266c9ed2e5ec037691e) on ipad? -- your imagination makes sense though.

Comment: @SqlZim yep looks that way. Also this avoids a sort at all with the right index. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7066db5f0320b88c4e3f069d1c09c8fd Whereas that remains in the `distinct` plan.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `group by` and use `distinct`:

```
select distinct Name, count(*) over() as Total
from t
where name in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WDMT68119

returns:

```
+------+-------+
| name | Total |
+------+-------+
| A    |    10 |
| B    |    10 |
| C    |    10 |
+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you count all of the records and then do a cross join on all the different names

```
SELECT a.NAME
    ,x.Total
FROM DataTable a
CROSS JOIN (
    COUNT(*) AS Total FROM DataTable
    ) x
GROUP BY a.NAME
    ,x.Total
```